# How to determine the date that Office 2003 was installed

Tags: .net, windows, ms-office

Is there any guaranteed way of determining the date that Office 2003 (and .Net Framework v2.0) were installed on a client computer?

I am trying to nail down a problem which I think is due to the order that the .Net Framework and Office 2003 were installed in, so I need a way I can get a client to have a look at their machine (preferably the file system) and let me know.

It may require admin privileges (or Registry etc) which wouldn't be a problem but not the preferred solution.

It appears that the folders under Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11 have a number with the same date which at first sight appear to be an installation date / time.

Likewise in Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727 there are two with the same date, but this seems less certain.

I could use WMI with a winmgmts:object and SELECT * FROM Win32_Product, but was wondering if there was a 'telephone' way to do it!

Comment: define 'telephone' way please

Comment: @fretje - I think that GalleySlave means a way in which he can call his client and tell him over the telephone what to look for.

Comment: @ChrisBD: I just experienced an *Aha-Erlebnis* :)

Comment: I ought to add that this ought to run on XP - I gather (@1800 INFORMATION) that Vista shows it in Add / Remove Programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GS, you're right, folders under Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11 will bear a Date Modified that is the date/time of installation.  Office11 is '03.

Comment: The Date Modified in \Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11 is much more recent than the installation date... there are some other folders that have much older dates (Queries, Samples, Forms + others)

Comment: Those are the folders I meant.  I have 12 of them, including the ones you mention, that have the same Date Modified.  Unless I'm mistaken, that's the date I installed Office.  Some other folders (Migration, Addins, Convert) have later dates, but they were created with later activity.

Answer (score 0):

Over the telephone, tell the user to run the "add remove programs" control panel and look for Office 2003?

Comment: I don't think that tells you *when* office was installed.

Comment: It does on my computer with Vista. I have visible columns Name, Publisher, Installed On and Size. There are also lots of other columns that can be added in